# Preventing mass form submits by $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

If I'm getting bombed by a .NET program created in C# - bombed as in the user is submitting the $_POST fields on my form in mass quantities... It's specifically my contact form.

I'm not sure how exactly the mass `$_POST` occurs in the .NET program or it even could be a c++ program, I have no idea. However I had an idea to counter this.

My first idea requires `$_SESSION` but... Would those `$_POST` bombing program(s) the user created handle/accept a `$_SESSION`?  I really don't want to find out but maybe someone with experience with the WebClient class in C# would know if it handled `$_SESSION'S` or whatever it is the user is using.  I was considering using `$_SESSION['submitted'] = $count;` and another part of `$count++;`

```
if($_SESSION['submitted'] > 5) {
    //display captcha or block from site
} else {
    $count++;
}
```

If the user's program didn't handle a $_SESSION is there anyway possible I can disable the site to them? So they can't attack my contact form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bypassing the session lockout is trivial for a malicious user. Just delete the session cookie after each POST and they get a brand new clean session with the limit reset.

The only secure way to block a user such as this is to start throttling their IP address. Limit it to a certain number of connection attempts per minute and they won't be able to submit than that many requests per minute. Now, if they can hop between hosts then you've got a bigger problem, and should probably look at moving your form elsewhere so all they get is a 404 (until they notice it's moved).

The downside is if they're using a common proxy or somethign like AOL which proxies EVERYTHING, you'd be blocking other legitimate users as well.

Comment: agree with that, we can add that you could check for all marketing user tracking code snippets available on the web for good ideas in user detection. Check for example http://panopticlick.eff.org/ look at all the data they collect and think about a unique visitor hash.

Comment: how can I throttle IP address? ATM my new method is inserting their IP & PHP Time into a mysql database, and running a cron job every 12 hours, deleting IP's older than 12 hours. If there are 5 of the same IP in the database it'll block them from contacting me.

Comment: That'd still let them hammer your server with requests. Best place to do it would be at the firewall, so the requests don't even reach Apache. If you're on linux, the iptables commands detailed at https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=34494, modified to work for port 80 instead of port 22, would work perfectly. I use something very similar to this to block SSH scans on my home machines.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can put some security barriers like a login form or some other form of authentication (like browser check or the like)

Aside from that the only think i can think of is to block the incoming IP, which then again might not be a good idea

Answer (score 0):

What about just implementing the CAPTCHA?

Answer (score 0):

Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but SESSION stores a cookie (or some other way) with the session id (a very long hash string), The SESSION variables are stored on the server. So even if they handled SESSIONs they would have no control over the server stored SESSION variables.

If I were you, I'd set CAPTCHA to always be on...